# TX and RX on different IP

Tags: sms, sms-gateway, smpp

I wonder if ESME allows this config:

Client is connecting with same system_id as TX from one machine (first IP) and as TRX from another (second IP)

```
        <--- TX (X.X.X.123)
[ MySRV ]
        ---> TRX (X.X.X.124)
```

As now seems that I sent Delivery reports to TX as I received it from it.

This should be programmed on software level right?
And malfunctioning is on my side?

Thanks for thoughts, just couldn't find similar situation on Google.

Regards,
Vedran

UPDATE: As I understand SMPP protocol more - if you encounter such problem you can always contact me. But at the end problem would be in your implementation.

Comment: nobody... :) Any toughs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to look a bit closer at your scenario.

If you use the TX session for DLRs (delivery reports) encapsulated in deliver_sm packets, then you are violating the specs and the malfuction is on your side.

A TX session is not allowed to receive deliver_sm packets. Checkout http://opensmpp.org/specs/SMPP_v3_4_Issue1_2.pdf, Section 2.3 for a list of allowed PDUs for different session states.

However it's possible to encapsulate DLRs in data_sm packets (added since smpp 3.4) too, which are allowed to be sent to a TX session. If you do this (although uncommon), it's up to you if you use the TX session or the TRX session. Do a round robin or use the session which originally sent the message, if still connected.

For compatibility reasons (as smpp 3.3 is still often used) I suggest to use deliver_sm for DLRs and therefore only send them to a RX or TRX session. So in your case it would be the TRX one.

Comment: Dear Martin, long time I had no comment on this as my understanding of SMPP was really basic. Now I got a bit older on this field and today I would find your answer good. But also I would not ask such question, if you get me :) So for now, just wanted to say thanks.